# LayoutRebuilder.ForceRebuildLayoutImmediate not rebuilding HorizontalLayoutGroup Unity

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine, layout, unity-ui

I'm working on a component where I need the correct anchored positions of children of a HorizontalLayoutGroup in the Start function.

I can force the HorizontalLayoutGroup to rebuild by doing:

```
public HorizontalLayoutGroup horizLayoutGroup;
public RectTransform exampleChild;

private void Start()
{
    horizLayoutGroup.CalculateLayoutInputHorizontal();
    horizLayoutGroup.CalculateLayoutInputVertical();
    horizLayoutGroup.SetLayoutHorizontal();
    horizLayoutGroup.SetLayoutVertical();

    Debug.Log(exampleChild.anchoredPosition);
}
```

But it seems odd that doing:

```
 public RectTransform horizRectTransform;
 public RectTransform exampleChild;

 private void Start()
 {
     LayoutRebuilder.ForceRebuildLayoutImmediate(horizRectTransform);
     Debug.Log(exampleChild.anchoredPosition);
 }
```

Does not work, because as far as I can tell from the source code LayoutRebuilder.ForceRebuildLayoutImmediate is calling the same functions:

```
public static void ForceRebuildLayoutImmediate(RectTransform layoutRoot)
    {
        var rebuilder = s_Rebuilders.Get();
        rebuilder.Initialize(layoutRoot);
        rebuilder.Rebuild(CanvasUpdate.Layout);
        s_Rebuilders.Release(rebuilder);
    }

    public void Rebuild(CanvasUpdate executing)
    {
        switch (executing)
        {
            case CanvasUpdate.Layout:
                // It's unfortunate that we'll perform the same GetComponents querys for the tree 2 times,
                // but each tree have to be fully iterated before going to the next action,
                // so reusing the results would entail storing results in a Dictionary or similar,
                // which is probably a bigger overhead than performing GetComponents multiple times.
                PerformLayoutCalculation(m_ToRebuild, e => (e as ILayoutElement).CalculateLayoutInputHorizontal());
                PerformLayoutControl(m_ToRebuild, e => (e as ILayoutController).SetLayoutHorizontal());
                PerformLayoutCalculation(m_ToRebuild, e => (e as ILayoutElement).CalculateLayoutInputVertical());
                PerformLayoutControl(m_ToRebuild, e => (e as ILayoutController).SetLayoutVertical());
                break;
        }
    }
```

And the whole purpose of it seems to be to rebuild layouts: [Wiki Entry](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.LayoutRebuilder.ForceRebuildLayoutImmediate.html)

> Forces an immediate rebuild of the layout element and child layout elements affected by the calculations.

So yeah I don't really have a problem with this necessarily I'm just wondering why it doesn't work as one would expect it to. If anyone has more info on this I would be thrilled to hear it!

Links to the source code for things:

[LayoutRebulider](https://bitbucket.org/Unity-Technologies/ui/src/0bd08e22bc17bdf80bf7b997a4b43877ae4ee9ac/UnityEngine.UI/UI/Core/Layout/LayoutRebuilder.cs?at=5.2&fileviewer=file-view-default)

[HorizontalLayoutGroup](https://bitbucket.org/Unity-Technologies/ui/src/0bd08e22bc17bdf80bf7b997a4b43877ae4ee9ac/UnityEngine.UI/UI/Core/Layout/HorizontalLayoutGroup.cs?at=5.2&fileviewer=file-view-default)

[HorizontalOrVerticalLayoutGroup](https://bitbucket.org/Unity-Technologies/ui/src/0bd08e22bc17bdf80bf7b997a4b43877ae4ee9ac/UnityEngine.UI/UI/Core/Layout/HorizontalOrVerticalLayoutGroup.cs?at=5.2&fileviewer=file-view-default)

[LayoutGroup](https://bitbucket.org/Unity-Technologies/ui/src/0bd08e22bc17bdf80bf7b997a4b43877ae4ee9ac/UnityEngine.UI/UI/Core/Layout/LayoutGroup.cs?at=5.2&fileviewer=file-view-default)

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Comment: @b.ben Well the first solution (calling everything manually) _does_ get it to recalculate the layout. I was just wondering why calling `LayoutRebuilder.ForceRebuildLayoutImmediate(horizRectTransform);` doesn't as well.